# Cloning existing disk to RAID 1 on ServeRAID M1015 (SAS9220-8I)?

Tags: windows, clone, ibm

I'm trying to clone an existing single disk (on Windows server) to RAID 1 via new ServeRAID M1015 / SAS9220-8I HBA card, but can't find in the card's bios options any way to do so.

Can anyone advice about this particular controller, if it possible to clone an existing disk?

The only other way I can think of, is making a new RAID-1 from scratch, then trying to clone the existing disk to it via disk cloning tools, but really prefer not to do this because of possible complications.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thought on building a new RAID 1 and cloning your existing install is correct, there really is no better way to do it.

You will either need to load the drivers for the new controller into the existing OS, or use an imaging product that supports alternate hardware restores.

EDIT: I mention the alternate hardware restore because I don't know what storage hardware your OS is currently running on.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. The OS running there is Windows, but the card is a Hardware Raid, so it should be transparent to OS.

Comment: Are you sticking with the same RAID card? If so, take an image, create the fresh RAID and apply the image.

Comment: Actually I'm adding a new RAID card to server, which previous soft-RAID has died. So I only need to install drivers to Windows to support the card, correct?

Comment: Also, I've tried connecting the card to MB and booting Windows from the current drive, so windows would recognize it and install the drivers - but the Raid card seems to overtake the system and forces me to boot from it - any idea how to sort it out?

Comment: You're gonna have to mess around with your BIOS boot order on that one.

Answer (score 0):

Once connected to the RAID card, the hardisks become unbootable, as in no operating system found.

If we disconnect the RAID card, connect the HD direct into the MB, they boot fine.

If we create a new RAID array, than apply the system image taken previously. will the new RAID be bootable